# How to save state of application in android?

Tags: android, state

I want to know how can I save state of my application in android.What I want is when user is using my app and in between he goes out of my app without doing logout.So when he again open my app he should be redirected to the page and its section where he left instead of first page.
Is it Possible to do ?
Please Help me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always play around with

```
SharedPreferences
```

and

```
Editor
```

you save a value that represents where your user got it and when you reopen the app you load the page accordingly like 1 => main page 2=>user info 3=>credits etc

either check the android documentation or :

http://saigeethamn.blogspot.com/2009/10/shared-preferences-android-developer.html

Comment: sure just let us know id its what you need

Comment: I tried the second option.I created a static variable which contains the info of last page where user left the app and it is working also. But I saw a strange behavior(atleast for me) when I am in app & presses a home button and go to home screen and again when I reopen my app so it goes to the page where I left and in same condition also that I left without checking value of static variable . I want to know how does it happen .